# How to send mail to another server using postfix?

Tags: postfix, mail

I have 2 servers:

In server 1, IP: 192.168.190.176, I have configured `main.cf`

```
myhostname = ubuntu
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = ubuntu, 192.168.190.171.ubuntu, 192.168.190.171
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

In server2, IP: 192.168.190.171, I have configured like so:

```
myhostname = ubuntu
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = ubuntu, 192.168.190.176.ubuntu, 192.168.190.176
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
```

When I send mail from server1 to server2 by command:

```
echo "Test" | mail -s "Test Postfix" quocchi@[192.168.190.171]
```

In server2, `/var/spool/mail/quocchi` is empty.

In server1: /var/log/mail.log

```
Apr 23 17:37:27 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[3452]: 17902800A9: from=<root@ubuntu>, size=311, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr 23 17:37:27 ubuntu postfix/local[3465]: 17902800A9: to=<quocchi@ubuntu>, relay=local, delay=0.34, delays=0.15/0.15/0/0.05, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Apr 23 17:37:27 ubuntu postfix/qmgr[3452]: 17902800A9: removed
```

In server2:

```
Apr 23 19:35:59 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[10688]: lost connection after CONNECT from unknown[192.168.190.17$
Apr 23 19:35:59 ubuntu postfix/smtpd[10688]: disconnect from unknown[192.168.190.176]
```

How can I set it up correctly?

Comment: Did you check  `/var/log/mail.log` to see if anything is wrong?

Comment: I updated in my ask, and i check in local quocchi mail and local mail receive that mail, but i want it send quocchi mail of server2

Comment: You have named both servers `ubuntu`. I guess that will confuse postfix as it will try to deliver the mail locally first.

Comment: I try with quocchi@[192.168.190.171] but, in /var/log/mail.log of server2 error lost connection after CONNECT from unknown. Can you fix it?